# Por que não consigo passa uma matriz como parâmetro de uma função em C?

Tags: c, funções, matriz, passagem-por-valor

Caros amigos, hoje me deparei com um problema que não consigo entender.
Ao tentar passar uma matriz como parâmetro, não consigo acessar os valores dos elementos, acabo acessando sempre os endereços de memória dos elementos da segunda linha pra baixo. Por que isto ocorre? Segue o código do meu programa que apareceu o erro.

Usei a biblioteca patrão stdio.h e a constante MAX

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
```

Chamada  na main:

```
int mat[3][3] = {8, 0, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 10, 2};
verifica_quadrado_magico(mat, 3);
```

Corpo da função:

```
void verifica_quadrado_magico(int matriz[][MAX], int dim){
int i, j, somaDP = 0, somaDS = 0, somaL, somaC, somaL0 = 0;
int igual = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        printf("%i\t", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//Continua, mas até aqui já é o suficiente para entender meu problema
```

A saída em tela foi esta:
[image: Imagem passando a matriz como parâmetro]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você define `MAX=10` e usa este valor como tamanho da dimensão secundária no argumento `matriz[][MAX]`, mas sua matriz tem dimensões `mat[3][3]`.

Quando o loop vai pular de linha na matriz, avança dez posições na memória e "cai fora" da variável.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, meu caro!

Answer (score 1):

O @Kahler já explicou o problema, que é ter um tamanho incorreto no parametro da função, mas a minha resposta mostra como resolver deixando o tamanho dinamico.

Se tentar colocar `matriz[dim][dim]` direto no parâmetro da função, sem alterar mais nada não vai funcionar e vai obter o seguinte erro de compilação:

> error: 'dim' undeclared here (not in a function)
>
> error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete

Para que funcione tem também que trocar a ordem dos parâmetros para que o `dim` venha primeiro, assim:

```
void verifica_quadrado_magico(int dim, int matriz[dim][dim]){
```

No seu código também tem algumas coisas que deve acertar:

- Deve usar o `dim` como limite dos `for`
- A inicialização da matriz no `main` deve usar `{}` para cada linha.

Exemplo simplificado e a funcionar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void verifica_quadrado_magico(int dim, int matriz[dim][dim]){
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < dim; j++){
            printf("%i\t", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int mat[3][3] = {{8, 0, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {3, 10, 2}};
    verifica_quadrado_magico(3, mat);
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/dn8s51)

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar isto no meu programa.